# Phonegap file/file-transfer plugin success but no folder in ios

Tags: ios, file, cordova, directory

I am trying to create a new folder 'Abc' and then download images from a url to it. It is working perfectly in Android and I see the folder/pics in the Gallery but not in ios.

Added some alerts which makes me feel that the folder and image is being downloaded fine in ios (success function is fired) but I am not able to see the folder anywhere. further, I am trying to share that image from the app itself and that functionality is also not picking the local image (again, working fine in Android). I am using the latest versions of the file and file transfer plugin with Phonegap 3.5

Here is the code i am using:

```
//in onDeviceReady
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);    
function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Abc",{create:true, exclusive: false},gotDir,onError);
}

function gotDir(d){
DATADIR = d;
alert(DATADIR.toURL());
}

var ft = new FileTransfer();

ft.download(imgurl, dlPath, function(entry) {
    console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    alert(entry.fullPath);
             },
  function(error) {
    alert(error.code);
    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
    console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
     }
    );
```

DATADIR.toURL() returns:

Android:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Abc/
```

ios:

```
file:///var/mobile/Applications/xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xx-xxx/Documents/Abc/
```

entry.fullPath returns:

Android:

```
/Abc/filename.ext
```

ios:

```
/Abc/filename.ext
```

But I don't see the folder "Abc" anywhere in Documents on iphone (ios 7).

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I am able to browse to the new directory on the mac (via ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator) when I run it in the Simulator and can further access it via SocialShare plugin but not in an actual device (tried on 2).

Another UPDATE:

I am now able to use the share functionality on the image downloaded in the new folder on the device. However, I am still not able to browse the new folder that was created. If it is being shared that means the folder is there but not accessible. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.xml file to see if you are using Library for iosPersistentFileLocation as described in the FileSystem docs (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md). Your code may be in Library.

Comment: Just checked and I don't see any preference set for iosPersistentFileLocation :(

Comment: Sorry, you got me there. Perhaps try using iExplorer (http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to find it?

Comment: Do you know if a folder is created from an app and images are saved to it, would it show up in Photos as a new Album or would it remain private to other apps (exclusive: false). Refer to my second update to the post.

Comment: I don't think so. If you look at the table of locations here (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md), none seem to imply the Photo Gallery.

Comment: Android is so much better... download a photo anywhere and it shows up in Gallery!! Seems like the folder that is being created via getDirectory is private to the app and cannot be accessed outside of it from within the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cordova-plugin-photo-library to show downloaded images to the phone gallery.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-photo-library

```
var url = 'file:///...';
var album = 'MyAppName';

//save Image
cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveImage(url, album, function (libraryItem) {}, function (err) {});

//save video
cordova.plugins.photoLibrary.saveVideo(url, album, function () {}, function (err) {});
```

saveImage and saveVideo both need write permission to be granted by requestAuthorization.